# Panel plot using lattice package in R

Tags: r, panel, lattice

I would like to make an xyplot using lattice with 2 panels one over the other corresponding to a variable(date) having 2 levels(Weekday and Weekend). My dataframe looks like this:

```
 interval    date      steps
1        0 Weekday 2.25115556
2        5 Weekday 0.44528000
3       10 Weekday 0.17316889
4       15 Weekday 0.19789778
5       20 Weekday 0.09895556
6       25 Weekday 1.59035111
 .
 .
 .  
289        0 Weekend   0.21462500
290        5 Weekend   0.04245000
291       10 Weekend   0.01651250
292       15 Weekend   0.01886250
293       20 Weekend   0.00943750
294       25 Weekend   3.51178750
```

I used the following code:

```
xyplot(steps ~ interval| levels(activity.week.mean$date), 
           data = activity.week.mean,
           type = "l",
           xlab = "Interval",
           ylab = "Number of steps",
           layout=c(1,2))
```

What happens is that I get 2 panels with both having the distribution of Weekend and Weekday but I need one for each. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `steps~interval|date`? It nice that you have the data included, but in general it is more helpful for someone trying to use these data when you use the output of `dput(activity.week.mean)`

Comment: Perfect! I actually tried this earlier but that was before I changed the date to a factor variable with 2 levels which messed up the results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `|levels(date)` you should be using `|factor(date)` or just `|date`

```
xyplot(steps~interval|factor(date),
       type='l',layout=c(1,2),
       xlab='Interval',ylab='Number of Steps')
```